# java lwuit port to C++

Tags: c++, lwuit

I found a port for lwuit to c++ in  in the lwuit-incubator (https://svn.java.net/svn/lwuit-incubator~svn trunk/telmap. but I am not able to make it compile because of missing some header files like "cmpl.h" , "TMArray.h" , "TMVector.h" "SmartPointer.h" .

Is there any one tried to use the c++ implementation for lwuit before? 
or is there any equivalent for lwuit in stranded c++ ?

Comment: What is the destination hardware and OS you want to run your application on?

Comment: actually my target is to run it on IPhone and WP7 , using Mosync cross mobile platform that support c++ as it is input languish.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com) for that (disclaimer: we wrote Codename One).

No one outside Telmap used that port to my knowledge, that port is based on LWUIT 1.1+ which is VERY long in the tooth and the chances of getting something at that level accepted at the appstore or Windows market are near zero.

That port doesn't have garbage collection support and uses only reference counting, it was used by Telmap to target older Symbian devices where the JVM was very badly implemented.